# Does the boundaries of non-disjoint sets in Euclidean space have common element?

Tags: general-topology

I've got stuck while solving a problem, and the thing I need is;
If you are given two open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, where they have both common element and non-common element. (That means, their intersection is nonempty and their relative complements toward each other are also nonempty). Then can I assure that their boundaries are also not disjoint?

Comment: What happens for $n=1$ when you consider to intervals with different endpoints?

Comment: Uhmm, I meant sets that are not disjoint..

Comment: Consider $(-1,1)\subset(-2,2)$.

Comment: You should exclude certain cases where the sets are nested away from the boundary of the larger set, since they would clearly not share a boundary point in that case.

Comment: @DavidMitra: You beat me to it! That's what I was thinking of in my comment.

Comment: Ohhh... Yes you're right I was so blanked so that I couldn't figure out that cases

Comment: Well, you need to add a few conditions. For example if the sets are open, not disjoint, not contained in one another, and connected ...

Comment: $(0,2)$ and $(1,3)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks, I realized that this assumption was such a dangerous one.

Comment: I didn't know that $(1,3)$ and $(2,4)$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 2):

As commenters pointed out, this is false as stated: e.g., David Mitra gave the intervals $(0,2)$ and $(1,3)$ as a counterexample.

Here is a positive result (a rather trivial one). Assume $\partial A$ is connected and the sets $\partial A\cap B$ and $\partial A\setminus B$ are not empty. Then $\partial A\cap \partial B$ is not empty.

Indeed, if $\partial A\cap \partial B=\varnothing$, then every point of $\partial A$ is either an interior point of $B$ or an exterior point of $B$. Then 
$$\partial A=(\partial A\cap \operatorname{int}B)\cup (\partial A\cap \operatorname{ext}B)$$
where both sets on the right are open and nonempty. This contradicts $\partial A$ being connected.

Comment: The positive result is still worthwhile! It shows that, in general, if you partially submerge a connected set in another set, it necessarily goes through the boundary.